# Flash page mirrored in cocoa webview in NSTabview

Tags: cocoa, flash, webview

I have a NSTabView with dynamically created tabs. Each tab contains a webview (created when tab is added). It works fine, but if a webview display a flash website, if you go to another tab, then back to flash one, flash page is upside-down (bottom of page is on top, completely mirrored).

Any idea about what happens and how to repair it ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by removing the NSTabView. I show and hide webviews when needed, and it works fine.